# Reactive Streams: How to wait for all publishers, by key?

Tags: java, rx-java2, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Suppose I have 3 publishers and 1 processor. The publishers emits items in the form `{key: <integer>, value: <object>, publisher_id: <string>}`.

The publishers makes IO operations, so:

- On the one hand, I'd like the publishers to work on (roughly) `N` items at a given moment.
- On the other hand, I'd like the consumer to **merge** the items to one single record (i.e. `{key: <integer>, values: <list>}`)

I've actually already implemented a `FluxProcessor` that has an internal storage (`ConcurrentHashMap`) to keep all the items. It manually `request()` new items whenever CAPACITY wasn't reached.

I'd like to know if there's a built-in functionality to do that with RxJava(2)/ Spring Reactor API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use merge, rebatchRequests and toMultimap with RxJava 2:

```
Flowable<KeyValuePublisher> source1 = ...
Flowable<KeyValuePublisher> source2 = ...
Flowable<KeyValuePublisher> source3 = ...

Flowable.merge(
    source1.rebatchRequests(N),
    source2.rebatchRequests(N),
    source3.rebatchRequests(N)
)
.toMultimap(kvp -> kvp.key, kvp -> kvp.value)
subscribe(map -> System.out.println(map));
```

Comment: Thank you akarnokd!

Comment: I have to admit that this not actually what I wanted, as `toMultiMap` is a "sink" which ends the `Flowable`

Comment: That do you mean by "ends the Flowable". You can [convert between types](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#converting-to-the-desired-type).

Comment: Do you happen to know what's the equivalent in Spring reactor?